# Как распаковать архив TAR.GZ размером 600+Гб на ssd 1Tb?

Tags: архивация

Есть ноутбук с SSD 1Тб, на нем в папочке лежит архив TAR.GZ объёмом сильно превышающим половину объема самого SSD (600+Гб). Оригинальный файл архива не требует сохранения, но нужна информация, которая внутри архива. Подктньте идей, как его можно распаковать без использования сторонних жёстких дисков. Всё ещё осложняется архитектурой CPU ноутбука aarch64 вместо x86_64. Но это уже мелочи.

Comment: если расспакованные данные меньше 1TB - то можно что-нибудь попробовать. Например: делаешь программу которая считывает немного байт из архива и сразу записывает их на ЖД, а из архива удаляешь эти пару байт.

Comment: А инфа из архива на диск-то влезет? Есть он сам на 600+ гиг, то в распакованном виде он наверное больше всего диска

Comment: Я бы предпочёл не рисковать и всё-таки достать откуда-нибудь сторонний жёсткий диск...

Comment: Инфы там на 890гиг должно влезть с лихвой. Уже пробую запилить скрипт.

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически, это можно сделать, так как gzip/deflate - потоковый формат. То есть, можно удалять уже распакованную часть архива с диска. Но вот есть ли на свете такой архиватор - это уже вопрос.

Возможно, придется вооружиться zlib и написать распаковщик с нуля, там относительно не сложно.

Идея такая - режем архив на чанки, скажем по сто мегабайт. Дальше просто - распаковали сто мегабайт - стерли чанк, и так далее.

Можно даже поступить более элегантно - некоторые ФС (ext4 в частности), позволяют при помощи вызова `fallocate` ([Deallocating file space](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html)) делать в файле дыру, обозначая, что это место файл больше не занимает(дальнейшее чтение их этого места будет выдавать нули вместо данных). Так что чанки можно не делать.

Answer (score 1):

Были полезны все ответы [отсюда](https://superuser.com/questions/265772/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-tar-file).

Я сделал небольшой скрипт на баше, который собирает в БД пути к файлам, потом монтирует архив как диск, скачивает оттуда файлы. Поначалу все файлы в алфавитном порядке без маппинга. Но потом переделал выборку файлов по конкретным смещениям в архиве.

Иными словами, когда архив примонтирован, файлы добываются без проблем в readonly режиме. И этим можно сносно пользоваться.

Но распаковать полностью так и не удалось. Удаление из архива длится целую вечность. Задачу можно решить на более низком уровне. Вероятно, пришлось бы даже вспомнить ассемблер.

Но с такими задачами надо обращаться к доктору в Кащенко.

Пришлось купить внешний терабайт.

Comment: *`"Пришлось купить внешний терабайт."`* -- вот это правильное решение (надеюсь внешний? Он  лишним в хозяйстве никогда  не будет)

Comment: Не нужен был ассемблер, только zlib, С и аккуратные вызовы  truncate/fallocate

Comment: @avp взял Samsung X5. И... чёрт бы его побери, я проморгал факт, что он не работает через usb((! Потому его использование, как флешки возможно только на компьютерах с NVMe/TB3+. Что крайне печально, так как я строил на него планы работать с планшета/мобильника. А так файл распаковался где-то минут за 10, это включая время, затраченное на копирование архива с ноутбука на винт. И стоило оно той траты двух выходных дней?!

Comment: @gbg cогласен, с ассемблером я погорячился. Я ковырял исходники и zlib и tar (обоих версий и gnu, и bsd). Но все равно `truncate` почему-то рубит файл слишком медленно. Да и почему-то медленно работал как `truncate` так и сами `fopen`/`fclose`. Плюс распаковывать архив с конца к началу не с руки. Под использованием ассемблера я имел в виду работу с ФС как утилита `dd`. Его исходники тоже хорошо просмотрел. Но до такой реализации я, слава богу, не дошел. Остановился, когда открыл исходники ext4.

Comment: @DiD А надо было не исходники читать, а man - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html, раздел Deallocating file space